# showing large table with QTableView with PyQt4

Tags: pyqt, qtableview

sorry, but im an newbie in PyQT.

Im trying to show a table with 300 rows with qtablview. With smaller tables everthing works fine. What do i have to change to show all rows?

```
from PyQt4 import QtSql, QtGui

class EmployesWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self, parent=None):

    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    # Connect to database
    self.__database__ = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    self.__database__.setDatabaseName('../db/stammdaten.db')
    self.__database__.open()

    # Create QTableView to show table's data
    self.tableGrid = QtGui.QTableView(self)


    self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self,self.__database__)
    self.model.setTable("employes")
    self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
    self.tableGrid.setModel(self.model)


    self.resize(800,400)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

solved it!: There was an error in columnsnaming in my database:

```
print (self.model.lastError().text())
```

gave me the answer.

Tanks anyway.